# Massive space between components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdialog, grid-layout

Please have a look at the following code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridLayoutTest2
{
    private final JDialog msgDisplayer;
    public GridLayoutTest2()
    {
        JLabel maleLabel = new JLabel("Male",JLabel.CENTER);
            maleLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            JLabel femaleLabel = new JLabel("Female",JLabel.CENTER);
            femaleLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

            JLabel fmaleIcon = new JLabel();
            fmaleIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/TESTING-Image.gif")));
            fmaleIcon.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());


            JLabel maleIcon = new JLabel();
            maleIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/TESTING-Image.gif")));
            maleIcon.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

            msgDisplayer = new JDialog();
            msgDisplayer.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1,1,1));
            msgDisplayer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            msgDisplayer.setTitle("Body Fat Percentage Classification");


            msgDisplayer.add(femaleLabel);
            msgDisplayer.add(fmaleIcon);
            msgDisplayer.add(maleLabel);
            msgDisplayer.add(maleIcon);

            msgDisplayer.pack();
            msgDisplayer.setVisible(true);
            msgDisplayer.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            new GridLayoutTest2();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This code contains a HUGE gap (space) between the labels and images screenshot attached). I do not want to have this space between labels and images. How can I eliminate it? I know I can go with the `GridBagLayout` to do it, but, is there any way in `GridLayout`? Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GridLayout` allocates an equals amount of space for all components based on the largest component in the container. If you don't wish to use a complex layout manager such as `GridBagLayout`, you could use **[BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)**,  which uses the component's preferred sizes. A `BoxLayout` with `Y_AXIS` alignment would be suitable here.

[Example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/YAxisAlignment.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I am moving with GridBag, which I am 100% familiar with :)

Answer (score 2):

Thats not the gap space, its real size of `JLabel`'s (maleLabel, fmaleLabel). Size of image determines size of parent `JLabel` and in `GridLayout`, all components will take size of largest component. Gap between components is 1 as you defined when setting layout. So solution of your problem lays in finding suitable layout manager.

Reimeus gave you an example of `GridBagLayout` and `BoxLayout`, and I would like to recommend you [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) which is quite easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Its the `Layout` what matters!!
Here I have done a short EG with my GUI builder to show the adjustment of white space(or the size of `JLabel`):

[image]

More white space:

[image]

Code:

```
public class udyfash extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public udyfash() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images.jpg"))); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("yooo!!");
    jLabel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(null, javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0))));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 405, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(44, 44, 44)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(39, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new udyfash().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
 }


 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
 }
```

We say GridBag is complex,but use the Layout Manager you are ok with.

Comment: Hello Joey, This is an auto generated code from the Netbeans, isn't it? I am sorry, but this style is not recommended in Java Community

Comment: @Sepala Yes, well once -TharshGod suggested me same thing(after that I have not used).But,this EG is not to show you the code, but to show that Layout makes a difference.

Comment: Yeah sure. You know, trust me, Netbeans drag and drop or Eclipse drag and drop is not acceptable in Java community. The reason is, the ugly code, non-user friendly variable and method names, code leaks (yes, there are!), and the inability to use design patterns or any kind of good software engineering concept related to GUI designing

Comment: agree :) but trust me, it was just to show you layout stuff :)

Comment: yeah yeah, I know :) . I was just explaining, that is all. :)

Comment: Yeah, non-devoting is one of policies. But it is applicable only to questions :D